# MSAccess VBA to Save a Single Attachment to a Folder

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm really new to Access so I haven't heard of most of the commands for Access VBA, but I am pretty familiar with Excel VBA.

What I'm trying to do is save the attachment that was just entered into a table through a form. I've been looking at some examples online and trying to get it to work for me but the code is not moving the file to the folder. I do not get a debug error though.

Here is my current code. I know it is set to loop right now, where really I just want the last attachment in the table each time, but I don't know how to get only the last attachment. Either way, this current code doesn't move ANY attachments.

```
Private Sub cmdAddRecord_Click()

If MsgBox("Adding a new record will save the current form. You will not be able to edit this credit request. Would you like to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Save current record and open new form") = vbYes Then

MkDir "C:\Users\username\Desktop\IC Transfer Back Up Attachments\" & Me.txtRequestID & "-" & "Back Up Attachments" & " " & Format(Date, "MMDDYY")

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

Dim SaveFolder As String
SaveFolder = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\IC Transfer Back Up Attachments\" & Me.txtRequestID & "-" & "Back Up Attachments" & " " & Format(Date, "MMDDYY")

Dim rsParent As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsChild As DAO.Recordset2
Set rsParent = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblICTRequested")
Set rsChild = rsParent.Fields("BackUpAttachments").Value

Do Until rsChild.EOF
    rsChild.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile SaveFolder
    rsChild.MoveNext
Loop

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCloseWindow
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmICTRequested"

End If
End Sub
```

Most of this seems to make sense to me, but I'm not sure what I should put in the `.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile` line, since I don't have a field named "FileData" but I've tried all my existing fields to no avail.

For reference, here are some of the online links I have reviewed:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29005769/MS-Access-attachment-file.html
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191852.aspx
https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=282135

Any tips? Much appreciated!

Comment: 1) Are you actually saving a document in a table? I would highly suggest against doing this. Much better to save the path to the file in the column rather than the object itself. 2) If you take my suggestion to heart, all you have to do is grab location of file from user (use a filelocation/selector so they select file) and then copy the file to the destination you'd like and then store path to file & filename in the column of the table.

Comment: @DougCoats Hi Doug! I should've stated that I didn't create the database, I'm just trying to get it to move each file as it is attached to the folder. The database does seem to be saving the document to the table. I can see the attachment in the table and open it up from there, so that part seems good. I'm assuming there was a reason for actually attaching the file instead of just the file path. However, I agree that if I had the file path I could just copy it. The database brings up a dialog box for the user to select the file(s), but I'm not sure how to grab the path from there.

Comment: http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2016/12/how-to-open-file-explorer-in-vba/

Comment: The attachment field in your table appears to be named `BackUpAttachments`. It is exposed as a `Recordset2` object containing fields named `FileData`, `FileName`, and `FileType`. As for why your code is not saving, you are only looking at the first row returned by `SELECT * FROM tblICTRequested`. Perhaps that row simply doesn't have any attachments? You could check `rstChild.RecordCount` to see if that is the case.

Comment: @DougCoats I should've been clearer when I said I don't know how to grab the path. What I mean is I don't know how to grab it from Access. I have done it in Excel the way you referenced, but in this database the user just selects a button to add an attachment and the file dialog box just appears, there is seemingly no code for it. I think Access just knows if the button is an "Attachment" type to bring up the dialog box. So I don't know where I could add any code to grab the file path, since it seems to do that stuff as a built in function or something.

Comment: @DougCoats sometimes the attachment field is valid. I use it in a DB where I need to pass the accdb around to people in various organizations (so they don't have a common network folder to reference, and I don't want to pass around a zip file and explain how to unzip it properly for attachments to work). This way the accdb always has all the files it needs and is self contained.

Comment: @Brad Fair enough but I still see it has a bad design choice. But seems like a personal style thing at this point.

Comment: When I first started working on this I figured I would take the approach Doug used, but when I was doing research I was finding more information on using the attachment field, so I went with that. I'm sure both would get the job done.

Comment: @DougCoats yeah, I mean..I'd rather not use Access for that particular task but my hands are tied.

Comment: I feel you @Brad I have to support numerous 97 access apps which if I had my choice sure woudlnt be the case lol

Comment: @TBoulz one disadvantage you might encounter quickly is that your DB can become more than 2 GB (the max accdb file size) easily if you are saving lots of files to it. If you know you won't get there, great, if you might then you may as well save everything to disk right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the help of someone, I changed the line:

`Set rsParent = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblICTRequested")`

To:

```
Set rsParent = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblICTRequested WHERE ID =" & Me.txtRequestedID)
```

This seems to be working perfectly for my purpose! Thank you to everyone who provided information!

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. I use a function like this:

```
Public Function SaveFileToDisk(FileName As String, FileData As DAO.Field2, Optional saveToFolder As String) As String
    Dim templatePath As String

    If saveToFolder = "" Or Not fso.FolderExists(saveToFolder) Then
        saveToFolder = Environ("temp")
    End If

    templatePath = GetAvailableFileName(FileName, saveToFolder, True) 'A function to create a unique file name

    FileData("FileData").SaveToFile templatePath
    SaveTemplateToDisk = templatePath
End Function
```

It gets called like this:

```
Dim tempPath As String
Dim fileData as DAO.Field2
Dim folderToSaveTo as string

folderToSaveTo = "C:\some\folder"
set fileData = rsParent.Fields("BackUpAttachments")
tempPath = exporter.SaveTemplateToDisk("Name of file.ext", fileData , folderToSaveTo)
```

The attachment field is kind of like a recordset withing a field.